# Can we reopen this question now it's been edited? (It's been reopened)

Tags: discussion, support

I've had an edit of this question here:

- ["Behind each other's back" <-- is 'other's back' correct here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126523/behind-each-others-back-is-others-back-correct-here)

The phrase "each other" causes problems for lots of students. I think this is a useful question. Could we try and reopen it fast before it gets stale, please?